# Get a Variable from id input value

Tags: jquery

i have input value = 99.

```
<input type="text" id="num" value="99" />
```

so i want use that number for my alert bootstrap. that number is not showing in my alert, it say "undefined"

my javascript :

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("num").value;
    $('#alert').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>ur number : "+window["x"]+"</div>");
</script>
```

i have tried using window. but it say "undefined".

Comment: Just use `x`...

Comment: Be consistent and also use `$("#num").val()` and execute AFTER load: `$(function() {  $('#alert').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>Your number : "+$("#num").val()+"</div>"); });`

Comment: @mplungjan, Whats wrong with `document.getElementById("num").value`? Just because OP tagged jQuery

Comment: For consistency's sake - because he on next line uses the jQuery. It makes the code harder to read. If I use jQuery, I only ever use stuff like `this.id` when I do not use jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery `.val()` method to be consistent.

```
<script>
var x = $("#num").val();
$('#alert').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>ur number : "+ x +"</div>");
</script>
```

If you want to set value on page load use jQuery `.ready` method

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x = $("#num").val();
  $('#alert').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>ur number : "+ x +"</div>");
});
</script>
```

Comment: it work sir using `$("#num").val();`

but not work if im using `document.getElementById("num").val();`
it will work too using `document.getElementById("num").value; 
$('#alert').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>ur number : "+ x +"</div>");

Comment: Because .val() is for jquery and document.getElementById("num") is pure javascript